# How are golang select statements implemented?

Tags: c++, multithreading, go

In particular, I have some blocking queues in C++, and I want to wait until any one of them has some item I can pop.

The only mechanism I can think of is to spawn a separate thread for each queue that pops from its input queue and feeds into a master queue that the original thread can wait on.

It seems kind of resource heavy to spawn N new threads and then kill them all every time I want to pop from a group of queues.

Does Golang implement some more elegant mechanism that I might be able to implement in my own C++ code?

Comment: I don't think you can wait on multiple condition variables in one thread using just standard facilities. Maybe you can invert the problem, and have the queues actively push into the "master" queue where they notify blocking threads now.

Comment: Go's select implementation is [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/select.go), maybe it can give you ideas.

Comment: https://github.com/tylertreat/chan

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't necessarily say that Go's `select` implementation is elegant, but I think it's beautiful in its own way and it's fairly optimized.

- it special-handles `select`s with a single non-default case
- it permutes the order in which cases are evaluated in order to avoid deterministic starvation
- it does an optimistic first pass over the cases looking for one that's already satisfied
- it enqueues on the internal sender/receiver queues of each channel using many internal, known only to the runtime mechanisms

  - it uses `sudog`s which are like lightweight goroutine references (there can be many `sudog`s for the same goroutine) that allow quick jumping into the goroutine stack
  - it uses the scheduler's `gopark` mechanism to block itself which allows efficient unparking on signal
  - when signalled and unparked, it immediately goes into the triggered case handler function by manipulating the `select` goroutine's program counter

There's no single overarching groundbreaking idea in the implementation, but you would really appreciate how each step was carefully tinkered with so that it's fast, efficient and well integrated with concept of channels. Because of that, it's not very easy to reimplement Go's `select` statement in another language, unless you at least have the `chan` construct first.

You can take a look at the reimplementations available in other languages, where the idea was redone with various degrees of similarity and effectiveness. If I had to reimplement `select` from scratch in another language, I would probably first try a single shared semaphore and, in case that didn't work, switch to a cruder, sleep-a-little-then-check-in-random-order strategy.

Answer (score -3):

Golang's `select` statement is inspired from the C `select` function (see the GNU libc [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html)), that is used for waiting I/O on a set of file descriptors. If your queues communicate using a socket or a pipe, you may use it.